# Building an object

Tags: java, design-patterns, object, constructor

I came across a rather unusual way to build an object of a class in this blog :
http://marchwicki.pl/blog/2010/11/building-a-pojo-in-an-elegant-way/. Is this a good way to do this. What are the benefits?

Comment: Can anyone explain why bother with an inner class? Why not just return the object from each setter?

Comment: @box9 - the inner class is the builder of the builder design pattern, so your question is essentially "why bother with the builder design pattern".  See the answers below about builder design pattern and the answers to other SO questions about the builder design patter, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern.

Comment: @Bert F - what I got from that SO question was that the Builder pattern allows setter methods to be chained, which I understood. But that still doesn't explain why the builder pattern is better than returning the object from each setter, since that would *also allow chaining of setters*. Am I missing a benefit of the Builder pattern?

Comment: @box9 - I feel you're really asking "why not use a simple constructor and setter methods to initialize an object? (a.k.a. JavaBean style of  initialization). It doesn't matter whether you return the instance from setters so you can chain setters - chaining only affects the readability of the code.  This answer explains why some prefer the builder pattern over the JavaBean style of init: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern/1953567#1953567.  If its still unclear, I think this would make a good SO question to ask & get some other perspectives about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I came across a rather unusual way to build an object of a class in this blog : http://marchwicki.pl/blog/2010/11/building-a-pojo-in-an-elegant-way/.

This is the **builder design pattern** with a **fluent interface**.

As you see from the article, the two ideas are complementary and often used together (which I've seen some call a **"fluent builder"**), so much so, that they are often confused as the same thing:

- The [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) abstracts and simplifies the construction of a complex object into simpler steps.

  - The builder pattern is discussed in the "Gang of Four"'s *[Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_(book)#Creational_patterns)* book
  - Joshua Bloch talks about builders as Item 2 in his book [*Effective Java*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PP1&ots=yXLgLjt2TY&dq=Effective%20Java%20Bloch%20Builder&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- A [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) is an API-style that uses contexts and method chaining to improve the readability of code.

  - See Martin Fowler's post about fluent interfaces:
    http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

Note that you can use the builder pattern without a fluent interface (e.g. a builder with simple setters).  You can also use the fluent interface idea in more contexts than just builders (e.g. to improve the readability of a set of overloaded methods with many parameters and parameter variations).

> Is this a good way to do this?

This **"fluent builder"** seems highly accepted as "a good way to do this" (at least based on the number of articles and blog posts I've seen proselytizing the idea).

> What are the benefits?

Each idea has its own distinct advantages/benefits.  For example, see:

- Builder - [When would you use the Builder Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328496/when-would-you-use-the-builder-pattern)
- Fluent Interface - [What's a fluent interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084503/whats-a-fluent-interface)

Answer (score 4):

The only benefit is readability.  By the way, this is an example of a [*fluent interface*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

A fluent interface seeks to provide an API that, when used, produces more readable code than a standard OOP API tends to provide.

Comment: isn't it also called builder-pattern?

Comment: @Srinivas: The fluent interface is an extension of the builder pattern. Or maybe a readable adaption/implementation of the builder pattern in Java with a good dose of DSL lore.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is what [Joshua Bloch](http://www.artima.com/intv/blochP.html) had in mind in [Chapter 2](http://www.sixwhits.com/documentation/SuggsDocs/Java/Effective%20Java%20-%20Programming%20Language%20Guide.pdf) of his "Effective Java".

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple example of the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). It allows the separation of the algorithm for creating a complex object from the parts that make up the object and the way they are assembled. [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29) explains the consequences of this pattern as:

> 1. *It lets you vary a product's internal representation*. The Builder
>      object provides an abstract
>      interface for constructing the
>      product. The interface lets the
>      builder hide the representation and
>      internal structure of the product. It
>      also hides how the product gets
>      assembled. Because the product is
>      constructed through an abstract
>      interface, all you have to do to
>      change the product's internal
>      representation is define a new kind of
>      builder.
> 2. *It isolates code for construction and representation*. The Builder
>      pattern improves modularity by
>      encapsulating the way a complex object
>      is constructed and represented.
>      Clients needn't know anything about
>      the classes that define the product's
>      internal structure; such classes don't
>      appear in Builder's interface. Each
>      ConcreteBuilder contains all the code
>      to create and assemble a particular
>      kind of product. The code is written
>      once; then different clients can
>      reuse it to build Product variants
>      from the same set of parts.
> 3. *It gives you finer control over the construction process*. Unlike
>      creational patterns that construct
>      products in one shot, the Builder
>      pattern constructs the product step by
>      step under the control of the user of
>      the builder object. Only when the
>      product is finished does the user
>      retrieve it from the builder. Hence
>      the Builder interface reflects the
>      process of constructing the product
>      more than other creational patterns.
>      This gives you finer control over the
>      construction process and consequently
>      the internal structure of the
>      resulting product.

A real-world example of this pattern is the `ProgramNodeBuilder` class in the Smalltalk-80 compiler sub-system. Source code is parsed by an object of the `Parser` class which is initialized with a `ProgramNodeBuilder`. The `Parser` object notifies its `ProgramNodeBuilder` object each time it recognizes a syntactic construct. When the parser is done, it asks the builder for the parse tree it built and returns it to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite happy to do my first stackoverflow post here - cause you are discussing my article :-)

I think this construction (leverage of both builder and fluent interface: fluent builder) greatly improves code readability. What is more (and not getting into discussion around design patterns) it proves its value when we need immutable objects. Simply, by making constructor private and removing all the setters, we gain a very powerful tool for an elegant and readable, yet powerful way of building immutable objects. Finally, the whole post was supposed to be more about smart usage of templates to generate repeatable code - but I pretty like the discussion.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! If you like to know more about my project please send me a message.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find using a Builder with a Fluent Interface very useful and very intuitive. You can express better your intents when sending messages to the builder.

I wrote a little example of a Builder with Fluent Interface, hope it helps.

http://jpereira.eu/2011/10/12/fluent-interfaces-while-trying-to-make-sense-of-prototype-pattern/