# Object reference vs Void return type for a Method

Tags: c++

I was looking at some open source source code and I noticed that for some methods, rather than using void for a return type, they had used a reference to that class.

Example:

```
class Object
{
private:
    float m_x;
public:
    Object();
    Object& setX(float x)
    {
        m_x = x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Normally, I would write the same function like this:

```
class Object
{
private:
    float m_x;
public:
    Object();
    void setX(float x)
    {
        m_x = x;
    }
};
```

Is there any advantage of using one over the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are some advantages with returning a reference. When returning a reference you can keep on working on the returned reference and chain multiple function calls together. For example if there were a `setY` function too, you could do this:

```
object.setX(5).setY(10);
```

Returning a reference doesn't really have disadvantages but allows some nice things. It can be used to create fluent interfaces, workaround the lack of named parameters in C++ if you want, and other things.

**Related reads:**

- [What does object.method1().method2() mean?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#method-chaining)
- [What is the “Named Parameter Idiom”?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-parameter-idiom)
- [What's a fluent interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2084503/1942027)
- [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I did not realize you could do that in C++.

Comment: This style is known as [“method chaining”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) or [“fluent interface”](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html).