# Why do some lines start with a period in C# during object creation?

Tags: c#

Referring to the example below, what is going on when the new logger is created? Several lines start with a ".". I'm guessing this is object initialization, but it doesn't seem like normal constructor arguments.

What is this syntax doing?

[image]

Comment: If you delete the whitespace (which is largely ignored by the compiler), do you understand the line then?

Comment: Given the fact that the `;` terminates your line, and the fact that you already have `.MinimumLevel.Verbose()` as an example it should be relatively apparent to you. No? It is just one long line of code split on several lines.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I understand that whitespace is ignored, but it seems like an odd way to create an object. Why not just have input arguments for each setting?

Comment: See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69519/when-to-go-fluent-in-c, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084503/whats-a-fluent-interface, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937755/what-is-the-difference-between-a-fluent-interface-and-the-builder-pattern/17937946

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a chain of methods and properties. You can take:

```
something.A.B().C.D().E.F();
```

And add newlines to write it as:

```
something
    .A.B()
    .C.D()
    .E.F();
```

More generally, this style of method chaining to configure an object is called a Fluent Interface.

Comment: You learnt me how it was called. Thank you ! Just adding [this post](https://assist-software.net/blog/design-and-implement-fluent-interface-pattern-c) in my comment as it illustrates with an example

Comment: Why is it necessary to create an object this way though? Why not just input arguments for each setting?

Comment: @Izzo The designer of that interface decided that it was a nicer (i.e. cleaner, easier to read and write) way of configuring the builder than calling individual methods or having lots of input arguments. I've added some links to a comment on your OP.

Answer (score 2):

The object is created here:

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
```

The next part is accessing a property on the new object:

```
.MinimumLevel
```

Followed by a method call on the object referenced by that property:

```
.Verbose()
```

And so on.

The entire statement represents a single expression, the result of which is assigned to the variable `logger`.